# Flutter firestore stream returns all entries as null

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So, I'm trying to get all docs from this collection in firestore, but they are all returning as null. Here is my code and results:

My model for a Spot:

```
class Spot {
  GeoPoint coordinates;
  bool covered;
  String excerpt;
  List<String> imgs;
  bool lighting;
  String name;
  bool public;

  Spot({
    this.coordinates,
    this.covered,
    this.excerpt,
    this.imgs,
    this.lighting,
    this.name,
    this.public,
  });

  factory Spot.fromMap(Map data) {
    return new Spot(
      coordinates: data['coordinates'] ?? null,
      covered: data['coveres'] ?? false,
      excerpt: data['excerpt'] ?? '',
      imgs: (data['img'] as List ?? []).map((v) => v as String).toList(),
      lighting: data['lighting'] ?? false,
      name: data['name'] ?? '',
      public: data['public'] ?? false,
    );
  }
}
```

Here i'm setting up my Stream:

```
final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 Stream<List<Spot>> streamSpots() {
    var ref = _db.collection('spots/DF/Brasília');
    return ref.snapshots().map((list) => list.docs.map((doc) {
          Spot.fromMap(doc.data());
        }).toList());
  }
```

And here I'm calling my stream:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<List<Spot>>.value(
          value: DatabaseService().streamSpots(),
          initialData: [Spot()],
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Maparkour',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: SplashScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My firestore collection has 14 entries so far, and that is being returned correctly, but every entry comes back as null!

Here's a pic from my debugger:

[image]

Any ideas as to why? Any help is apreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to return a value when iterating through `list.docs`. You should add an arrow function or a `return` statement on your stream.

```dart
return ref.snapshots().map((list) => list.docs.map((doc) => Spot.fromMap(doc.data()) ).toList());
```

or

```dart
return ref.snapshots().map((list) => list.docs.map((doc) { return Spot.fromMap(doc.data()); }).toList());
```